# Trying to make UISearchController function like language settings in iPhone in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I currently have implemented a UISearchController which is currently working fine.  Here are the attached screens that show how:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, what I would like to do is implement it in a way that looks like how Apple implemented their language selection option in settings on the iPhone:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In Apple's implementation, the search bar does not hide the navigation bar when it is active.  Does anyone know how to achieve this functionality in Swift instead of the conventional way which I have implemented currently?  Just wondering.

Comment: Can you share your code so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property called [`hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618650-hidesnavigationbarduringpresenta) in the `UISearchController` class that by default is `true` that handle what do you want, so put it in `false` and you can achieve keep the navigation bar during the presentation as Apple do in the Language options:

```
searchbBarController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

I hope this help you

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.